# how to display a JLabel when hover over an image?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I just created a JLabel and added an image to it.

What I want is, that when someone clicks this image, a blue bar under it is displayed as shown in the image and that blue bar would contain two more buttons that could perform an action... need your help guys!!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSizn.png]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post any code with what portions are not working?

Comment: What's the question? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: i have done nothing so far.. i have just created a jlabel and added an image to it.. what i want is, that when someone clicks this image or just hovers over this image a blue bar is shown under it.. just like when we hover our mouse to the right in windows 8 a bar with some settings option pops up

Answer (score 0):

Use a JButton instead of a JLabel, then add an ActionListener to the button

Comment: actually the image which should be clicked is a circle.. if i add an image to the button would it become round shaped or will stay in square shape?

Comment: alright so there is no issue with the shape.. this is what i wrote in the ActionListner    "_bar.setBounds(30, 30, 80, 80);
    _bar.setBackground(Color.white);
    _bar.setOpaque(true);
    add(_settingsbar);
    _bar.setVisible(true);"                                            _bar is the name of the jlabel i wanna display under the button... but this doesn't show anything .. @FredK

Comment: @NelsonJohn You can undecorate the button, turning of its borders and special content area, when set to transparent, it will look just like a label